# How to use @Input to set a Pipe in a *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive, ngfor

I have a component that has 3 input parameters

1. json_columns
2. json_rows
3. name_filter

**How can I make it so the `name_filter` is set as the pipe to filter that group of data?**

#### component.ts

```
@Input('json_columns') columns:[{}];
@Input('json_rows') rows:[{}];

//Pipe 
@Input('name_filter') filter:string;
```

#### component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of filas | filter: searchItem; let i=index" >
{{item.nombre}}
</tr>
```

Comment: How many such `pipes` do you have? Why not use a single `pipe` and then filter the `properties` by name, id etc, instead of having multiple filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a function ‘getFilas()’ and implement the filter in the function

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-data-in-component

This is the template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of getData(); let i=index">
    {{i}} -  {{item.name}} {{ item | json }}
</div>
```

This is the relevant code in the component

```
  @Input() field: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() data: any[];

  getData() {
    return this.data.filter((item) => {
      return item[this.field] == this.value;
    })
  }
```